# Converting binary search tree to linked list

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to convert a binary search tree to a linked list. The linked list should have the smaller numbers in the front and the larger numbers in the back (smallest to largest). I need to create a function that takes in a binary search tree tree and outputs a linked list.

```
        4
      /   \
     2     6
   /  \   / \
  1   3  5   7
```

Here's my binary search tree. I need to make the linked list this way: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. Here's my current code:

```
node<int>* makeLinkedList(binary_tree_node<int>* root_ptr);

int main()
{
    binary_tree_node<int> *s1 = sample1();  //Creates the tree

    node<int>* node1 = makeLinkedList(s1);  //invokes function to make a linked list

    //Loop to print out the values of the linked list
    for (node1; node1 != NULL; node1 = node1->link()){
        cout<<node1->data()<<endl;
    }
}

node<int>* makeLinkedList(binary_tree_node<int>* root_ptr){
    node<int>* left;

    if (root_ptr == NULL) {
            return NULL;
    }

    else{

        left = makeLinkedList(root_ptr->left()); 
        list_head_insert(left, root_ptr->data());  //list_head_insert inserts a new entry at the head of the linked list
        return left;
    }
}
```

When I run my code, the output is 4, 2, 1. I just don't understand how I can convert this binary search tree into a linked list from smallest to largest. I've tried putting list_head_insert function on top of the recursive call, but the output is nothing and the list is empty.

Answer (score 3):

So in other words you want this in sorted form in your linked list.

There's a way of traversal for that: In-Order Traversal. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)
 for more info on traversals.

So how to do this, though? As a hint I'll give you a function to "print" the contents of this BST in-order. That should get you rolling. (As after figuring out how to get contents of the tree in-order, all you have to do is just call an insert function to your list)

```
void print_in_order(Node* t) {
    if(!t)
        return;
    print_in_order(t->left);
    cout << t->data;
    print_in_order(t->right);
}
```

Comment: I understand in order traversal and how to print the contents of the tree, but I don't know how I can insert the contents of those nodes to my linked list.

Comment: It's quite straightforward. Using the method above, with a few modifications, you can add elements to your list. Simply after getting an element in this recursive manner, call a function that'll help insert an element to the list. As an additional hint, when do you actually get to have an element from the tree? Do you have to really go until t is null? When can you stop?

Comment: `makeLinkedList(root_ptr->left()); 
  list_head_insert(list2, root_ptr->data());
  makeLinkedList(root_ptr->right()); 
  
  return list2;` This is what I have right now, the program compiles, but it exits out because of some problem. Is this what you are talking about doing?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Make sure that you check if the pointer recevied is null.

Comment: I have a base case statement that checks if the pointer is null like this: `if (root_ptr == NULL) {
            return NULL;
 }`Is this what you mean?

Comment: Hmm, here's one thing. You don't need the return value from the makeLinkedList function. Send two parameters, one for BST node and one for your linked list. Update your list that way if you aren't doing so already. Also, I forgot to ask, what kind of error is it that you're getting?

Comment: `makeLinkedList(root_ptr->left()); 
  list_head_insert(list, root_ptr->data());
  makeLinkedList(root_ptr->right()); ` This is where the error is in my code. I tried shifting my code to the way you said with the two parameters, but it's giving me the same error. The error is not a compilation error, but rather a run time error.

Comment: You need to debug your code then. Maybe your insertion is not working, maybe the list is not being updated properly. With what you've shown so far only speculations can be made.

Comment: @user2896120 forget the BST for now. Make certain the linked list implementation has no errors without the added complexity of the BST.  Prove the list out on a simple dataset, then when you know it works, go back to the BST.

Comment: @SenselessCoder It's not the insertion, it's the `root_ptr->left() and root_ptr->right()` For some reason, it has an infinite loop or something

Comment: @SenselessCoder Ahh, I know what I was doing wrong. I wasn't passing the list in the recursive call. My function prints this out: `1 1 2 3 2 3 2 2 4 5 4 5 4 6 4 7 6 4 7 6 4 6 4 4` I don't understand why it's doing all this and not just `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

Answer (score 0):

```
class HeadAndTail<T> {
    LinkedListNode<T> head;
    LinkedListNode<T> tail;

    public HeadAndTail() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
    }

}

public class Solution {

     public static LinkedListNode<Integer> constructLinkedList(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root) {
        return construct(root).head;
    }

    public static HeadAndTail<Integer> construct(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root) {

        if(root == null) {
            return new HeadAndTail<>();
        }

        if(isLeafNode(root)) {
            LinkedListNode<Integer> node = new LinkedListNode<>(root.data);
            HeadAndTail<Integer> headAndTail = new HeadAndTail<>();
            headAndTail.head = node;
            headAndTail.tail = node;
            return headAndTail;
        }

        LinkedListNode<Integer> node = new LinkedListNode<>(root.data);
        HeadAndTail<Integer> forLeftPart = construct(root.left);
        HeadAndTail<Integer> forRightPart = construct(root.right);

        node.next = forRightPart.head;
        HeadAndTail<Integer> headAndTail = new HeadAndTail<>();

        //if left part is null
        if(forLeftPart.tail != null) {
            forLeftPart.tail.next = node;
            headAndTail.head = forLeftPart.head;
        } else{
            headAndTail.head = node;
        }

        //if right part is null
        if(forRightPart.tail != null) {
            headAndTail.tail = forRightPart.tail;
        } else {
            headAndTail.tail = node;
        }

        return headAndTail;
    }


}
```